# How to dynamically display a content document image on a site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, url, contentdocument

I have created a dynamic url to display a logo image from content document. I uploaded the image and logged into the org and can see the image. When I use an incognito window the link gets broken but my urls look the same. I used ContentVersionId as record Id. What am I missing?

Visualforce:

```
    <apex:image id="theImage" value="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{!logoid}" width="300"/>
```

Apex:

```
try{
            urlsContentDistribution = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl, ContentDownloadURL , name, ContentVersionId  FROM ContentDistribution WHERE RelatedRecordId = :accs[0].id];
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('An exception urlsContentDistribution occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }


for(ContentDistribution logo:urlsContentDistribution){
        if(Logo.name.contains('Logo')){
           logoId = logo.ContentVersionId;
            system.debug('logoId: '+logoId);
        }
```

Logged in(renders correctly):

```
https://salesforce--test.aaXX.visual.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xx00000xOXxxXXX
```

Incognito(Broken link):

```
https://salesforce-test.secure.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068xx00000xOXxxXXX
```

Comment: Are you using the page on force site when you open in incognito?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes, every thing else is shown but I end up with a dummy image.

Comment: you need to make the images public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, files visibility is for internal users.
You need to create a content document link and content distribution for the file.

If you want the access to all file automatically you need to write a trigger.

Trigger

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    ContentTriggerHandler.createPublicLinkForFile(trigger.new);
}
```

Handler

```
public class ContentTriggerHandler {
    public static void createPublicLinkForFile(List<ContentVersion> contentVersions){
        system.debug('in ContentTriggerHandler');
        ContentDocumentLink[] contentDocumentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        ContentDistribution[] distributionsToInsert = new List<ContentDistribution>();
        Set<Id> contentDocId = new Set<Id>();
        for(ContentVersion objContentVersion : contentVersions){
            contentDocId.add(objContentVersion.ContentDocumentId);
        }

        Map<Id,ContentDocument> contentDocMap = new Map<Id,ContentDocument>([Select id, ParentId From ContentDocument WHere ID in : contentDocId]);

        for(ContentVersion objContentVersion : contentVersions){
            if(contentDocMap.containsKey(objContentVersion.ContentDocumentId)){
                Id parentId = contentDocMap.get(objContentVersion.ContentDocumentId).ParentId;
                if(parentId != null){
                    contentDocumentLinks.add(createContentDocumentLink(objContentVersion.ContentDocumentId, parentId));
                    distributionsToInsert.add(createContentDistribution(objContentVersion.Id));
                }
            }
        }

        insert contentDocumentLinks;
        insert distributionsToInsert;
    }

    public static ContentDocumentLink createContentDocumentLink(Id contentDocumentId, Id parentId){
        ContentDocumentLink objDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        objDocLink.ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId;
        objDocLink.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
        objDocLink.ShareType = 'V'; // Inferred permission
        objDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; //All users
        return objDocLink;
    }

    public static ContentDistribution createContentDistribution(Id contentVersionId){
        ContentDistribution newDist = new ContentDistribution();
        newDist.ContentVersionId = contentVersionId;
        newDist.Name = 'External Link';
        newDist.PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false;
        newDist.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
        return newDist;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this solution already only the downside is that it for all inserts, but thanks anyway. Seem there is no other way to do this dynamically. For now I chose to do this trough a static resource. Pitty this cant be done with functional salesforce setting.